# logback line number is not showing up in logs

Tags: java, logback

I am using logback 1.2.3 . My configuration looks like below

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <Target>System.out</Target>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%p [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %c{3}:[%C{1}:%M:%L] - [%t] - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
       <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

But I am not seeing the line number in my logs

```
INFO [2018-01-12 07:06:54] c.v.s.f.FlowStoreWarmer:[?:?:?] - [FlowStoreWarmer_flow_cache_warmup_thread] - no work to do for cid 19099
```

Can some one let me know what is going wrong?

Comment: Just for information : be to know that having the lines on your log take resource, and so impact the performance of your application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your encoder as below:

```
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%p [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %c{3}:[%C{1}:%M:%L] - [%t][%file:%line] - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
```

**[%file:%line]** means show source file name and line number.

Comment: I want to replace certain strings in my logs so used the pattern `%p [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %c{3}:[%C{1}:%M:%L] - [%t][%file:%line] - %replace(%.-20480m){'[^A-Za-z0-9=<>:@\\-\\[\\]\n\\s!]','_'}%n` . Replacement is working fine. But line numbers are not showing. Any thoughts?

Comment: I tried. The line number works correctly. But your code has several errors. Your replce syntax was wrong. It should not contain '<' or '>'. And before the last letter'n', there are some Zero-width characters.Just delete the <pattern> tag, and type it manually.

Comment: It is working. The zero-width character was causing the main issue. I replaced '<' & '>' with `&lt;` & `&gt;` . Can  you post this as an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380436/line-number-is-not-showing-up-with-replace-pattern-in-logback-xml  so that I can accept the answer?

Comment: Haha~ glad you worked out. No need to post for reputations. You can post your solution there.

Comment: Ok. I will post it. Thanks again.