# logback doesn't print method or line number

Tags: logging, groovy, logback, slf4j

This is in a Gradle project using Groovy for the app code as well as test code. But I'm using a logback.xml file for configuration.

One factor here that may be significant is that I am using the Groovy [@Slf4j](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/logging/Slf4j.html) annotation to provide a logger.

The `%method` and `%line` conversion words usually get printed out as "invoke" and "-1" respectively (although sometimes "invoke0" with "-2").

Interestingly, it does sometimes print the method and number: for example when it's an `ERROR` level log with an `Exception` parameter:

```
log.error( 'indexSearcher.indexReader.close() threw Exception', e )
```

... I presume that's something to do with the `e` object carrying with it "location" data which logback can then exploit. But just occasionally an `INFO` level message gets printed with the method and line number: it's quite puzzling.

I've seen people having problems with an async appender, but my appender is ROLLING_FILE ([RollingFileAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html)). This is not an extension of an async appender.

I've tried other remedies documented in other SO questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940230/logback-asyncappender-unable-to-print-method-name-and-line-number)): I've added these lines to my appender:

```
<includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
<param name="locationInfo" value="true" />
```

... did not solve the problem.

Someone somewhere said that it was necessary to ensure debug data was switched on at some point. In a Groovy context I'm not sure how I might try that idea.

Comment: the problem appears because groovy makes dynamic calls by default. for test - try to annotate with @CompileStatic just one method and it will print correct method name and line number.

Comment: @daggett Thanks very much for clearing up this mystery.  I don't know enough to understand why "dynamic calls" should lead to this strange phenomenon, and specifically for this particular module: beyond my pay grade.

Comment: groovy searches all the methods in runtime rather then during compile-time. and calls them indirectly - for example through reflection [Method.invoke(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-)

Comment: Yep, understand that: Groovy is obviously a dynamic language ... I still don't understand at all why dynamic method-calling could lead to such malfunctioning, particularly intermittent malfunctioning, of a module like logback: I'm surmising that somehow stack frame information gets stripped away... sometimes.  I may try looking into it but don't have much expectation that I'll understand (let alone find a solution).

Comment: Linking to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221240/logback-line-number-is-not-showing-up-in-logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**logback.groovy**

```
appender("STDOUT", ConsoleAppender) {
  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level {%logger} - %class.%method:%line - %msg%n"
  }
}
root(DEBUG, ["STDOUT"])
```

**X.groovy**

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@GrabResolver(name='maven2',root='http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/')
@Grab(group='ch.qos.logback', module='logback-classic', version='1.2.3')
@Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-api', version='1.7.30')

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Slf4j
class A {
    def f() {
        log.info 'msg-info-2'       //line 11
        log.with{
            info  'msg-info-1'      //line 13
            //new Exception("test").printStackTrace(System.out)
        }
    }
}

def a = new A()
a.f()
```

The command `groovy X.groovy` prints:

```
12:24:43.134 [main] INFO  {A} - A.f:11 - msg-info-1
12:24:43.139 [main] INFO  {A} - sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0:-2 - msg-info-2
```

---

**why**

in logback there is a class [CallerData](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/CallerData.java) with method `extract` that extracts caller data information as an array based on a `Throwable` parameter and returns an array of `StackTraceElement`. It tries to cleenup the stacktrace, however for groovy it could be really complex.

For example if you uncomment the line `new Exception("test").printStackTrace(System.out)`

You'll see stacktrace like this:

```
java.lang.Exception: test
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ... + 11 elements
    at A$_f_closure1.doCall(X.groovy:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ... + 15 elements
    at A.f(X.groovy:12)
    ... + 20 elements
```

CallerData tries to skip the technical groovy elements from stacktrace but fails to detect the right one.

---

**solution**

It's possible to modify the [`Framework Packages`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/LoggerContext.html#getFrameworkPackages()) for the logback context.

I don't know how to do that from `logback.xml`, but I found how to do it using `logback.groovy`

**logback.groovy** (modified)

maybe for your case you have to add another framework (ignored) packages...

```
context.getFrameworkPackages().addAll([
    "sun.reflect", 
    "java.lang.reflect", 
    "org.codehaus.groovy", 
    "groovy.lang.MetaMethod",
    "jdk.internal.reflect"
    ])

appender("STDOUT", ConsoleAppender) {
  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level {%logger} - %class.%method:%line - %msg%n"
  }
}
root(DEBUG, ["STDOUT"])
```

with this configuration the code above prints lines correctly:

```
13:12:14.410 [main] INFO  {A} - A.f:11 - msg-info-2
13:12:14.416 [main] INFO  {A} - A$_f_closure1.doCall:13 - msg-info-1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This looks amazing. I'm going to see how to switch from an .xml file to a .groovy one for the config. Since I started using Groovy I've been aware of the incredible stack traces you get. `StackTraceUtils` has a `sanitize` and even `deepSanitize` methods to try and address this.  No doubt your solution comes at a cost (time) but... wow! (NB I wonder whether Ceki, the author of logback, might be able to enlist these `sanitize` methods to make things functional in a Groovy context)

Comment: I've tested this quite a bit: it works sometimes but doesn't (so far) solve the problem. From my first experiments, it still often prints "invoke" and "-1", particularly when the log message contains interpolated Groovy placeholders (or whatever you call them: ${var}). Also it sometimes doesn't print the method properly: "core.MiscSpec.$spock_feature_1_2:38": line 38, yes, but that feature also has a name.  Could it be that yet more packages need to be added to the framework packages?

Comment: with `core.MiscSpec.$spock_feature_1_2` there is nothing to do - because after compilation that could be a real class/method name... to detect additional framework packages you could add to the pattern `%class` placeholder and when you see incorrect classname - just add its package to the list.

Comment: +1 Madam/Sir, I salute your genius! I included `%class` and that revealed another package to include: "jdk.internal.reflect"... now I'm really getting results. I'm going to suggest an edit to your answer for the sake of future readers of your answer.